# Parse data of size about 3MB using json in ANDROID?

Tags: android, json

I have to parse data by HTTP request of size about 3MB, through JSon, but the parser that I am using is unable to do so. here is the JSon parser:

```
public static JSONObject getJSONfromURL(String url){

    InputStream is = null;
    String result = "";
    JSONObject jArray = null;

    //http post
    try{
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();

    }catch(Exception e){
          //  Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
    }

    //convert response to string
    try{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),102400);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result=sb.toString();

    }catch(Exception e){
           // Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
    }

    try{

        jArray = new JSONObject(result);            
    }catch(JSONException e){
           // Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
    }
    return jArray;
}
```

Any help will really be appreciated. THANKS

Comment: Please specify "unable to do". Exception, Warnings, Log?

Comment: Can you please mentioned the data that you want to parse. otherwise the link to get that data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're parsing whole 3MB string in memory. It causes out of memory exception. Parse large data in stream:

- [JsonReader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html) since API level 11
- [Android JSON](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html) library or for large data [Jackson Streaming API](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonStreamingApi)