# Out of memory exception in gson.fromJson()

Tags: android, json, gson, out-of-memory

I use the following code for converting Json string(strWebserviceResult) to my Object:

```
EntMyClass entMyClass = gson.fromJson(strWebserviceResult,EntMyClass.class);
```

When **strWebserviceResult** is large (about 2.5 MB) I get the **Out of memory** exception on this line on Android phone devices not in Tablet that has larger memory.

How can I solve that.

Does anybody have any suggestion?

```
05-26 15:52:49.607: E/dalvikvm-heap(2078): Out of memory on a 9200-byte allocation.
05-26 15:52:49.618: E/dalvikvm(2078): Out of memory: Heap Size=31879KB, Allocated=27693KB, Bitmap Size=936KB, Limit=32768KB
05-26 15:52:49.618: E/dalvikvm(2078): Extra info: Footprint=31879KB, Allowed Footprint=31879KB, Trimmed=7400KB
05-26 15:52:49.618: E/AndroidRuntime(2078): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-19
05-26 15:52:49.618: E/AndroidRuntime(2078): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: (Heap Size=31879KB, Allocated=27693KB, Bitmap Size=936KB)
05-26 15:52:49.618: E/AndroidRuntime(2078):     at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:123)
05-26 15:52:49.618: E/AndroidRuntime(2078):     at com.google.gson.DefaultTypeAdapters$CollectionTypeAdapter.deserialize(DefaultTypeAdapters.java:664)
05-26 15:52:49.618: E/AndroidRuntime(2078):     at com.google.gson.DefaultTypeAdapters$CollectionTypeAdapter.deserialize(DefaultTypeAdapters.java:624)
05-26 15:52:49.618: E/AndroidRuntime(2078):     at com.google.gson.JsonDeserializerExceptionWrapper.deserialize(JsonDeserializerExceptionWrapper.java:51)
05-26 15:52:49.618: E/AndroidRuntime(2078):     at com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationVisitor.invokeCustomDeserializer(JsonDeserializationVisitor.java:92)
05-26 15:52:49.618: E/AndroidRuntime(2078):     at com.google.gson.JsonObjectDeserializationVisitor.visitFieldUsingCustomHandler(JsonObjectDeserializationVisitor.java:117)
05-26 15:52:49.618: E/AndroidRuntime(2078):     at com.google.gson.ReflectingFieldNavigator.visitFieldsReflectively(ReflectingFieldNavigator.java:63)
05-26 15:52:49.618: E/AndroidRuntime(2078):     at com.google.gson.ObjectNavigator.accept(ObjectNavigator.java:120)
05-26 15:52:49.618: E/AndroidRuntime(2078):     at com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContextDefault.fromJsonObject(JsonDeserializationContextDefault.java:76)
05-26 15:52:49.618: E/AndroidRuntime(2078):     at com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContextDefault.deserialize(JsonDeserializationContextDefault.java:54)
05-26 15:52:49.618: E/AndroidRuntime(2078):     at com.google.gson.DefaultTypeAdapters$CollectionTypeAdapter.deserialize(DefaultTypeAdapters.java:663)
05-26 15:52:49.618: E/AndroidRuntime(2078):     at com.google.gson.DefaultTypeAdapters$CollectionTypeAdapter.deserialize(DefaultTypeAdapters.java:624)
05-26 15:52:49.618: E/AndroidRuntime(2078):     at com.google.gson.JsonDeserializerExceptionWrapper.deserialize(JsonDeserializerExceptionWrapper.java:51)
05-26 15:52:49.618: E/AndroidRuntime(2078):     at com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationVisitor.invokeCustomDeserializer(JsonDeserializationVisitor.java:92)
05-26 15:52:49.618: E/AndroidRuntime(2078):     at com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationVisitor.visitUsingCustomHandler(JsonDeserializationVisitor.java:80)
05-26 15:52:49.618: E/AndroidRuntime(2078):     at com.google.gson.ObjectNavigator.accept(ObjectNavigator.java:101)
05-26 15:52:49.618: E/AndroidRuntime(2078):     at com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContextDefault.fromJsonArray(JsonDeserializationContextDefault.java:67)
05-26 15:52:49.618: E/AndroidRuntime(2078):     at com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContextDefault.deserialize(JsonDeserializationContextDefault.java:52)
05-26 15:52:49.618: E/AndroidRuntime(2078):     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:551)
05-26 15:52:49.618: E/AndroidRuntime(2078):     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:498)
05-26 15:52:49.618: E/AndroidRuntime(2078):     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:467)
05-26 15:52:49.618: E/AndroidRuntime(2078):     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:417)
05-26 15:52:49.618: E/AndroidRuntime(2078):     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:389)
05-26 15:52:49.618: E/AndroidRuntime(2078):     at org.mabna.order.businessLayer.BoWebService.getDataForUpdate(BoWebService.java:188)
05-26 15:52:49.618: E/AndroidRuntime(2078):     at org.mabna.order.ui.ActToolDataExchange.threadGetDataForFullUpdate(ActToolDataExchange.java:371)
05-26 15:52:49.618: E/AndroidRuntime(2078):     at org.mabna.order.ui.ActToolDataExchange.access$9(ActToolDataExchange.java:362)
05-26 15:52:49.618: E/AndroidRuntime(2078):     at org.mabna.order.ui.ActToolDataExchange$33.run(ActToolDataExchange.java:603)
05-26 15:52:49.618: E/AndroidRuntime(2078):     at org.mabna.order.utils.Utilities$5.run(Utilities.java:778)
```

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6173396/940096) helps you

Answer (score 6):

Try using the [fromJson](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#fromJson%28com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader,%20java.lang.reflect.Type%29) method that takes a JsonReader as input instead. This should allow you to not need the whole input string to be in memory at one time. Here's some sample code:

```
        final HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        final InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(c.getInputStream());
        final JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(isr);
        final EntMyClass entMyClass = GSON.fromJson(reader, EntMyClass.class);
        reader.close();
        c.disconnect();
```

Comment: My initial data is an encrypted string. I decrypt it to a string and I have strWebserviceResult as string. How can I convert strWebserviceResult to `InputStream`?

Comment: encrypted string -> cleared strWebserviceResult as a json string -> My Object

Comment: Maybe you can store the decrypted string to a local file first? You should then be able to get an InputStream from the local file.

Answer (score 6):

As with the other post, I would ask whether there is any way to avoid large memory usage with your app.  If you can do that, it will be the most optimal solution.  If your app really needs that much memory, you can try setting `android:largeHeap="true"` for your application in the manifest.  Here is the reference:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#AndroidManifestApplication_largeHeap

See this video for more information:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk

Comment: This solution is not adviced because it also increase the GC time (as there is more memory to process)

Comment: this is not the right solution. Increasing the memory will only delay the OOM, it'll not solve it.

Answer (score 3):

First of all. Do you really need to load 2.5MB data into memory?
At first there is created a big string, then it's parsed (another objects in memory), and then there is created a huge instance of EntMyClass. This approach is really inefficient.

I guess you have List in this object. Having only information you've provided I'd suggest to stream data into database. Then you can create adapter to show data in ListView.

There is a lot of ways how to do it. I'm using Jackson library because is the fastest, GSON should have similar functions.

Assuming you have a list in this object below is example how to store json array in database:

```
    //create parser
    final JsonParser jsonParser = objectMapper.getJsonFactory().createJsonParser(inputStream);

    JsonToken jsonToken = jsonParser.nextToken();
    while ((jsonToken = jsonParser.nextToken()) != null && jsonToken != JsonToken.END_ARRAY) {
        //map json object to ItemClass
        final ItemClass item = jsonParser.readValueAs(ItemClass.class);
        //store in database
        itemDAO.insert(item);
    }
```

And surround it with database transaction, not only data will be rollback in case of error but it's also more efficient.

Comment: The answer is what I want

Answer (score 0):

Please, read the answer from the author of gson - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9460267/394678)

And my 5 cents:

```
        JsonReader r = null;
        try {
            Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            r = new JsonReader(reader);
            result = gson.fromJson(r, clazz);
        } finally {
            if (null != r) {
                r.close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Dmitry. How can I convert my string to InputStream (`is`)?

Comment: Which encryption/decryption algorithm you are using for this string? Why I'm asking it? The reason is that you need to organize processing of this string by small chunks, not whole 2.5mb, in other words - partial processing.

Comment: `public String getClearedResponse(String decryptionPassword)
   throws Exception
 {
  String zippedString = Crypto.decrypt(this.content, decryptionPassword);
  return Utilities.decompress(zippedString);
 }`

Comment: it has unzip procedure also :(

Comment: Actually, it should be something like this: public InputStream getClearedResponse(String decryptionPassword) throws Exception { return new BufferedInputStream(new GZIPInputStream(Crypto.decrypt(is, decryptionPassword))); }.

And in your Crypto.decrypt you need to implement your [CryptoReader](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/thinking_in_java/TIJ314_009.htm).

Is it your own crypto algorithm?