# Android & Gson memory leak

Tags: android, memory-leaks, gson

This simple example of Android Application project (in Eclipse). Look at the difference in code samples and between pictures of memory snapshots. Seems that calling com.google.gson.Gson.toJson causes memory leak.
Sample 1 (line calling printObject is commented):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
...
@Override protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    // Log.v(TAG, ">>> ACTIVITY  [onRestoreInstanceState] config:"+printObject(savedInstanceState));
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
public String printObject(Object object)
{
    try  { return new Gson().toJson(object); }
    catch (Throwable ex){return "[FAILED to PRINT Object] : "+ex.getMessage();}
}
}
```

Sample 2 (in short same code as 1 except UNCOMMENTED Log.... line. So WITH call to printObjet):

```
...
@Override protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    Log.v(TAG, ">>> ACTIVITY  [onRestoreInstanceState] config:"+printObject(savedInstanceState));
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

And here is Eclipse Memory Analyzer snapshots for Sample 1 and 2 respectively after 62 times (for each case) rotating tablet device to cause Activity restart:

[image: For Sample 1:]

[image: For Sample 2:]

And "Leak suspect" for green area of second image:

> Problem Suspect 3
>
> 62 instances of "com.example.leaktest.MainActivity", loaded by "dalvik.system.PathClassLoader @ 0x416beb30" occupy 1,959,008 (24.72%) bytes.

Used in test: Eclipse 4.2 / Gson 2.2.2 (and 2.1) / Android 4.2 / Android Tablet with 4.1.1

There are some similar issues from the net:
[here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-gson/RMvIhv4mAP8), [and here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10765831/out-of-memory-exception-in-gson-fromjson)

Question: Is it an issue (in Android or Gson)? Or i have missed the lesson :) ?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is `62 instances of "com.example.leaktest.MainActivity"`, unrelated to Gson. There's lots of information on avoiding activity leaks, including [this post](http://android-developers.blogspot.ca/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html) on the Android Developers' blog.

Comment: Please read attentively. Sample 1 has NO leaks. With same testing conditions. Another deal if you tested the same code sample yourself and you came to another results. But i doubt.

Comment: By the way i'm almost sure that it's related to Gson. Because the root of problem started from another chunk of code where Memory Analyzer shown Leaks suspect with NN instances of Gson.

Comment: The code above is the only code added to template Android App project. So what you see is the only place where bad things could happen. Can you point the place where for your opinion i made a mistake?

Comment: @far.be I also detected a memory leak in my app and tracked it down to Gson (at least what it looks to me). Did you dig into this any further and/or did you find the reason why Gson probably leaks?

Comment: @Oliver Hausler Nope and Nope unfortunately.