# Gson toJson convert OutOfMemory(OOM)

Tags: arrays, kotlin, bitmap, out-of-memory, android-bitmap

```
val gson = GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create()

Log.e("surveyListPretreatment",gson.toJson(
    SurveyTab(viewModel.owner.treat).apply {
        surveyListPretreatment = viewModel.surveyTabs.surveyListPretreatment
    })
)
```

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 150994952 byte allocation with 25165824 free bytes and 103MB until OOM, max allowed footprint 118228816, growth limit 201326592

**Because,**

the DTO has

```
var imgByteArray:ByteArray? = null //bitmap convert byteArray => It's OOM Generated...
```

how can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jake Wharton already commented about this on [GitHub Issues](https://github.com/google/gson/issues/1176).

> There's no magic fix. You either need a larger heap or a smaller
>   object.

If you can do make your object smaller, it will be the most optimal solution. If your app really needs that much memory, you can try setting `android:largeHeap="true"` for your application in the manifest.

Reference:

1. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#AndroidManifestApplication_largeHeap
2. [Out of memory exception in gson.fromJson()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10765831/out-of-memory-exception-in-gson-fromjson)